# Como testar um envio de dados de um formulário com Jasmine JS

Tags: javascript

Como eu consigo realizar um teste de envio de dados de um formulário usando Jasmine?
Por exemplo, eu preciso testar se o meu formulário aceita um cadastro sem nenhum dado inserido, ou se o meu formulário aceita um cadastro com dois CPF'S iguais, e mais testes parecidos.